# using #if to use old / new method code

Tags: if-statement

I have question is possible use #if to use old / new method.

Example:

```
#if (Old)
public void method1()
{
    //code
}
#else
public void method1()
{
    //code
}
#endif
```

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to C#:

You can do this, see here for an example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691099(v=vs.71).aspx

Remove the brackets around Old in your example, and #define Old or don't.

Typically you would define the directives in the project properties under a build configuration.